# Closing of a question about an unexpected behavior of a math software

Tags: discussion, closing, closed-questions

Compare these two questions.

| Question | [4011197](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4011197) | [4009941](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4009941) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| title | [Why is there a difference between MATLAB and manual calculation for eigenvectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4011197) | [Linear Programming in R using lpSolve dismisses constrains](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4009941) |
| status | open | closed |
| sample problem | compute eigenvectors of $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&2\\0&1&2\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$ | $\max A + B + C + D$ subject to $A + 2B + 3C + 4D = 10$ $A, B, C, D \in \{0,1\}$. |
| theoretical result | $\lambda_1 = 1, v_1 = (1,0,0)^T$, $\lambda_2 = 2, v_2 = (6,2,1)^T$ | $A=B=C=D=1$ |
| procedures | `A = [… ; … ; …]; [P D] = eig(A)` | `library(lpSolve)` `f.obj <- c(1,1,1,1)` … `lp("max", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs, binary.vec = 1:4, all.bin=TRUE)` |
| computed results | `{(1,0,0), (-1,0,0)}` for eigenvalue of `1`; `{(640/683, 640/2049, 320/2049)}` eigenvector for eigenvalue of `2`. | `A=1, B=1, C=0, D=1` |

Both questions ask for the reason for the error.  Why do we allow one question open while another one is closed?

P.S. Credits to @MartinSleziak for his table

Comment: I haven't taken a very close look, but the one that is closed (at the moment) is about using `lpSolve` or another method for computing. That is *definitely* off-topic, I haven't looked at the other one. But if that other one is literally about the choice of library to use, that's off-topic.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The OP of the closed question asks for an algorithm (say, simplex algorithm), which is language-independent and should be on-topic here.  The open questions concerns the `eig` method, which is a core part in MATLAB, which means "matrix lab".  However, judging from whether it belongs to the core syntax or not seems absurd, as software components evolve from time to time.  One module can get included or kicked out from the core part in an update.  I'm still puzzled why we leave another one open.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the closed question, which I voted to close, the guy specifically asks about a code problem with R, which has nothing to do here. Maybe the question could be rephrased to be on topic, but as is, it's not. That he asks for another algorithm is only tangential, his main problem, is with code, and his question *"Can anyone understand why this is so?"* is about this code, and we can't do much about this because it's likely a bug or an obscure feature. And we can't help either to find another program to handle this problem, it's not the purpose of MSE to give software advice.

The question about eigenvectors in Matlab looks loosely similar, but the outcome is different: the output is correct in the sense that 1) since the matrix is defective, there is no way to find three independent eigenvectors anyway and 2) it is [documented](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html) that for defective $n\times n$ matrix $A$, Matlab returns an $n\times n$ matrix $V$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $AV=VD$. It's a mathematical question, and we can explain this, and it's even likely to help other readers.